# What does "À l'œuvre, on connaît l'ouvrier" mean?

Tags: sens, proverbes, moyen-français

I know "À l'œuvre, on connaît l'ouvrier"  is a proverb, but what does it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that one knows the worker by looking at his work.

*À* followed by a noun, like in this sentence, can introduce a means. It's somehow similar to known locutions such as *à vue d'œil* or *à pied*. Other common examples:

> On le reconnait à la couleur.
>
> Cela se juge au poids.

Comment: An expression/verse with a similar meaning that also uses “À” in this manner is  “[Vous les reconnaîtrez **à** leurs fruits](http://context.reverso.net/translation/english-french/know+them+by+their+fruits).”